# How many HP is repaired by Crafter's Eyepiece?

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, crafting

The description of the [Crafter's Eyepiece](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=427) item says (emphasis mine):

> When you Repair an item, increase the Hit Points restored by 15 per proficiency rank *instead of 10*.

However, the description of the [Repair](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=42) action says (italics for emphasis mine):

> **Critical Success** You restore 10 Hit Points to the item, *plus an additional 10* Hit Points per proficiency rank you have in Crafting (a total of 20 HP if you’re trained, 30 HP if you’re an expert, 40 HP if you’re a master, or 50 HP if you’re legendary).
>
> **Success** You restore 5 Hit Points to the item, *plus an additional 5* per proficiency rank you have in Crafting (for a total of 10 HP if you are trained, 15 HP if you’re an expert, 20 HP if you’re a master, or 25 HP if you’re legendary).

So either the Crafter's Eyepiece meant "instead of 5", or it only works on a Critical Success. The latter is unlikely, Critical Success is always mentioned if it is a requirement.

Has this just remained from the playtest? How much HP has Repair restored there?

**More importantly, should Crafter's Eyepiece say "increase the Hit Points restored by 10 per proficiency rank instead of 5"?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Fixed by Errata

The [Crafter's Eyepiece](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=427) now specifies:

> When you Repair an item, increase the Hit Points restored to 10 + 10 per proficiency rank on a success or 15 + 15 per proficiency rank on a critical success.

Comment: The [errata has arrived](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=427)

Comment: @SpearCarrier.no2 Good spot! I'm failing to see *which* batch of errata this arrived in. Any ideas? I'm not finding it when I search for "Crafter's" or "Eye" on the errata page on Paizo's site. If it's on AoN it's been fixed, so I'm updating the answer, but I'm wondering when it was fixed.

Comment: Should an answer be changed like this? Wouldn't it be better to post this as a separate answer?

Comment: @ESCE: It looks like the 4th printing was released in January 2023, alongside [changes to the errata process](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo6si7o) (so that they would be released twice a year in spring and fall, rather than being tied to a new printing of the physical books). The [Wayback Machine's archive of the page from January 18, 2023](https://web.archive.org/web/20230118003735/https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=427) still shows the old description, so I'm guessing this change was in the "spring" errata and they haven't updated the `/faq` page to list those changes yet.

Comment: @Anagkai, I think in this specific case it is fine.

Comment: Related meta discussion: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12416/should-an-answer-be-rewritten-completely-if-new-external-info-becomes-available?cb=1